# How to get caret Index in a password box in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a virtual keyboard, which is working fine in *TextBox*. But same is not working in *PasswordBox* only when I change the cursor position using mouse.

I just want to get the caret index in *PasswordBox* , so that I can insert the text at right position.

Please let me know if its possible to find the caret index in *PasswordBox* too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this method for my VirtualKeyboard:

```
TextCompositionManager.StartComposition(new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, _PasswordBoxControl, "StringYouWantToInsert"));
```

The text get inserted at the carets postion.

Comment: You're welcome! Mark it as answer if it helps you. ;)